# A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Type'

Tags: powershell

I am trying to set the registry key using below command , but somehow the type parameter is not accepted . can anyone correct me if there is a parameter mistake . But when I see the regedit the type is Reg_Dword

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName @("ServerName") -ScriptBlock{Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKU:\UserSession\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" -Name "ProxyEnable" -Value 1 -Type "DWord"}


A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Type'.
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-ItemProperty], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SetItemPropertyCommand
+ PSComputerName        : ServerName
```

Answer (score 2):

[`Set-ItemProperty`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty?view=powershell-6) does not have a parameter named `-Type`. It only modifies existing properties and you can't change the type. So, if you want to modify an existing property just omit the parameter.

If you want to create a new property you can use [`New-ItemProperty`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-itemproperty?view=powershell-6) which has a parameter `-PropertyType` you can use for that.

Comment: "Type is a dynamic parameter that the Registry provider adds to the Set-ItemProperty cmdlet. This parameter only works in the registry drives." [From the docs.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-itemproperty?view=powershell-5.1)

Answer (score 1):

Older versions of power-shell do not have the -Type property.  You should check the version of powershell, and possibly revert back to using something like this:

```
[Microsoft.Win32.Registry]::SetValue("HKEY_USERS\UserSession\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings","ProxyEnable",1,[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::DWord)
```

Also, I don't believe "HKU\UserSession" exists.  Did you mean HKCU?